# Percentage question in GRE

Tags: percentages, number-comparison

Ashley's score was 20% higher than Bert's score. Bert's score was 20% lower than Charles Score.

Is Ashley's score greater than Charles Score?

This is essentially a GRE question however my mind can not get around it essentially the answer is that Charles has a higher score than Ashley. Which does not make sense to me. If I apply assigning values to each of the 3 people lets say Ashley has a score 100 which is 20% higher than Bert making Bert's score 80 whereas Bert's score is 20% lower so Charles score should be 96. However I figured out how to solve it which was assigning a value to Charles rather than Ashley but the question is why.

Comment: 20% higher than 80 is (80+0.2*80)=80+16=96, not 100.

Comment: That is the point don't think you understood the question. I did come to 96 but the answer is that Charles score is higher than Ashley not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example, Let Ashley's score=100. Ashley's score is 20% > Bert's score.
$$ Bert\times 1.2= Ashley.$$
$$Bert \times 1.2 = 100$$
$$ Bert = \frac{100}{1.2}=83.3333$$

Now Bert is 20% less than Charles. So
$$Charles - 0.2\times Charles = Bert$$
$$Charles(1-0.2)=Bert$$
$$Charles=\frac{Bert}{0.8}=\frac{83.3333}{.8}=104.16666$$

Clearly with these numbers, there is some rounding error, but

Check; 
Ashley is 20% > Bert:$\qquad$  $83.3333\times .2 +83.3333\approx 100$

Bert is 20% < Charles $\qquad$ $104.16666 - .2\times 104.16666 \approx 83.3333$

Comment: Thankyou this clears things up !